# How to show data from db with wysiwyg using php mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

How to show data from db with wysiwyg using php mysql ?

First, This is data in my dababase

```
 __________________________________________________________
|__id__|______________________message______________________|
|  1   |   aaaaaaa                                         |
|      |      aaaaaaa                                      |
|      |         aaaaaaa                                   |
|______|___________________________________________________|
```

Then , i use php

```
<?PHP
include("connect.php");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM message WHERE id = '1'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$datas=mysql_fetch_array($result);{
$message = stripslashes(str_replace('\r\n', '<br>',($datas['message'])));
}
echo nl2br($message);
?>
```

for show data from mysql, And then i get this.

```
aaaaaaa
aaaaaaa
aaaaaaa
```

I want to get this

```
aaaaaaa
   aaaaaaa
      aaaaaaa
```

How can i do that ?

Comment: try `echo "<pre>".$message."</pre>"`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are producing HTML as the output, you need to replace the spaces by "&nbsp;" (non-breaking space) characters, because HTML truncates multiple consecutive whitespace characters (such as spaces, ends of lines, etc.) into one.

Comment: That's why you can put your output between `<pre>` tags and save all these whitespaces.